# jqgrid pagination issue with display records dropdown

Tags: jqgrid

I am facing below issue in a jqgrid that has pagination:
Consider my resultset has 12 records and my Display Records dropdown has options `10,20` to select for the number of records to be shown at a time.

***step1*** - when I load the grid for the first time, Display Records  has value `20` and I can see `12` records in the grid.
***step2*** - Now I select `10` from the Display Records; the grid refreshes and i can see 10 records. Selected page is 1 of 2. ***step3** - * Go to second page of this resulteset;
the grid refreshes and i can see `2` records. Selected page is 2 of 2 ***Step4** * Now I change the value of Display Records to 20; the grid refreshes and I can see no rows in the grid.

This is happening because when I change the value of Display Records, the page number should be passed as 1 always, but it is being incorrectly passed as current value and hence my SP is returning incorrect result. Any solutions?

I am using jqgrid version 3.5.2

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with latest version of jqGrid - can you consider upgrade?

Comment: I tried upgrading to 3.6 but couldn't redo some of the customizations that I am having in plugin code.

Comment: I see that **you have to update to jqGrid 4.4.1** (not to other very old version 3.6). The version 3.5.2 is really very very old. It's like the usage of non-digital photos now. Probably many customization which you use are already in the box in the current version of jqGrid.

Answer (score -1):

### set page_num =1 when the page_num is grester than one and total records count is less than Display Records :

if page > 1:
    if int(request.get('hidden_total_records_count')) <= int(req.get('result_per_page')):
       page = 1

this coding is in python ..Share your entire logic too for better answers.